# How to get value of PATH environment variable programatically in Android?

Tags: android

I wanted to implement a file search function in my Android application and I am wondering how can i get value of "PATH" environment variable from within my program?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd need $PATH for a search program? Just walk the filesystem from the root of interest.

Comment: i am implementing a logic to ensure that device is not rooted. Therefore, i am going to go after folders in the PATH variable in addition to standard locations of the files for rooting and maintaining root access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> variables = System.getenv();
```

Iterate through keylist, if PATH exists, findout corresponding value from the map. see this [link](http://www.codebeach.com/2008/02/get-environment-variables-in-java.html) if it helps.

Comment: Use System.getenv(String name) instead

Answer (score 1):

.. or you can run adb

```
adb shell echo \$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i was looking for a programmatic way.